# Slow loading custom listview and Force close on some phone

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, asynchronous

My listview has 12 item with 12 picture in size 600*600 and on android emulator,I see below log:

```
     I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(432B)      AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 45MB/45MB, paused 32.860ms total 102.481ms
      I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21(928B) AllocSpace objects, 1(3MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 51MB/53MB, paused 5.177ms total 96.504ms
      I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 43(1664B) AllocSpace objects, 1(3MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 54MB/56MB, paused 1.513ms total 104.015ms
       I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 296 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
          I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Unfortunately This warning caused error on some phone(i think it's maybe for low memory).

Below is code of my list view,I googled above error and know i must use of thread.Can you help me to make it?

```
      public class ItemActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Variable {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_list);



     populatecantactlist();//fill listview with my item
     registerClickCallback();//What to do when click on item




    }



private void populatecantactlist() {


    ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new mylistAdapter();

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class mylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private  mylistAdapter(){
        super(AlbumActivity.this,R.layout.album_list_item,albumnames);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

        View item_view=convertView;

        if(item_view== null){

            item_view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.album_list_item,parent,false);
        }

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        iv.setImageResource(icon_num[position]);

        TextView tv1=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        tv1.setText(albumnames[position]);

        return item_view;}

}







private void registerClickCallback() {

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        //I want to after on each item select go to new activity which populate with
        //information about new album

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewclicked,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent i2=new Intent("com.example.ItemActivity");




            Bundle extras=new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("PositionItemClicked", position);
            i2.putExtras(extras);


            startActivity(i2);


        }});
}
```

UPDATE:I use below async but it had error:

```
       public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        iv.setImageResource(icon_num[position]);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to load the adapter in asynktask?

Comment: I search for asynctask and just found for loading image of url,can you help me?

Comment: only add your methods inside the asynktask.  in onPostExecute